# Global common navigation bar for multiple sites

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, web-component

I have multiple individual sites. I'd like to add a top navigation bar to all of these sites that should be common and updated at the same time. but don't want to repeat copy paste code in every site. What's the best way of doing it?

Can I use WebComponent for this? Would I be able to add/attach the component by simply adding a script tag to all the individual sites referring to a javascript file hosted elsewhere?

Are there any other options or best practice?

Answer (score 1):

What you have describe (aka componentization) is a kind of best practice.

There are so many options (ex: 3rd party JS libraries) that it's out of the scope of Stackoverflow to list then.

You can achieve this with Web Components.

Create a Javascript file in which you define a Custom Element for your navigation bar.

**nav-bar.js**

```
define.customElements( 'nav-bar', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = `
                <style>
                    :host { display: block ; border: 1px solid gray }
                </style>
                <button>Main Page</button>
                <button>About</button>
            `
    }
}
```

In every website, add a `<script>` tag to load you Javascript file. It can be hosted anywhere on the Internet, for example on a CDN site.

```
<script src='path/nav-bar.js'></script>
```

Add the custom element in your web page at the position you want:

```
<nav-bar></nav-bar>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I was also thinking along the same line. Plus, I'm thinking of addidng extea bit of code in that javascript to attach the custom element to the body upon page load. That way I all I have to do in the component site, is add the script tag. Would you be able to name some of the libraries you mentioned?

Comment: @aver Bootstrap, jQueryUI, Angular, React... but last two are complete framework so maybe too heavy for what you want to do